# project SVN repo paths reduced to "[]" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Installed Eclipse Kepler, Subclipse 1.8, SVNKit. Several (not all) of my projects now have only "[]" instead of the usual path into the repo. I can't see any obvious relationship between those that still have a full rpo path and those that now have on "[]". The two solutions to similar problems mentioned here (though none were identical) do not work:

- renaming the project, then renaming it back -> no change
- disconnecting the project then using "share project" -> complains that there is no SVN metadata data in the root of the project (except that there is)

The two other solutions recommended, namely "reinstall everything" and/or "delete the project (retaining files) and re-import it into the workspace" I want to keep as absolute last resort.

The situation is complicated by the fact that the SVN info associated with the projects is old and needs upgrading. A disconnected project cannot be shared, because it there is no "upgrade" option (just "Apply patch" and "Share Project"). A connected project with a "[]" path cannot be upgraded because the option is greyed out, along with everything else on the "Team" menu except Commit, Create Patch, Apply Patch, Show Revision Graph, Add to Version Control, Revert and Disconnect.

A further difficulty is that some of the "[]" projects are newer than their repo versions, with changes I want to preserve. So discarding the local copies and checking out new ones is not an option, at least not for all affected projects.

So, what I specifically want is some way to re-connect those projects with a repo path of "[]" to their correct repo paths. Some explanation of what the heck happened would be a bonus :-)

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all of the things you mentioned, I would guess that the working copy is not the right format.  The current version of Subclipse is 1.10.x which would require a Subversion 1.8 working copy format.  Team > Upgrade would be available to update it.

You said you have Subclipse 1.8.x installed, so that would requires a Subversion 1.7 working copy format. If the working copy is from a lower version then you could upgrade it, but if the working copy is from Subversion 1.8, then it will not be able to read it.

Comment: Thanks Mark, you are right, but I specifically mentioned that as a complication and explained why I could not upgrade the working copy format. The option is greyed out ("[]" projects) or not present at all (disconnected projects). Do you have any suggestions for working around this? It's not the main problem though. The main problem is the "[]" repo path. I want to reconnect them to teh correct path.  By the way. ALL projects had the same working copy format, but only SOME now have a "[]" repo path

Comment: The [] exists because it cannot read the working copy.  I am suggesting you do not have an option to upgrade because it is perhaps a newer format.  There is no way to downgrade the format.  I would start by moving to Subclipse 1.10.x so that you are using the latest version.

Comment: I stayed with 1.8 because the version of JavaHL library that Ubuntu 13.10 provides is 1.7.x. However, that gave me nothing but trouble, so I have since moved to SVNKit, which if I understand correctly supplants JavaHL. If my understanding IS correct, can I upgrade to 1.10.x if I use SVNKit?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the important bit of your previous answer: "The [] exists because it cannot read the working copy". Forgive me for asking you, bust is this fact or assumption? I ask because all of my projects use the same format (10, from Subclipse 1.6), but only some of them are showing "[]".

Comment: Yes you can upgrade.  No it is not fact.

Comment: Solves, sort of. I reinstalled Kepler, then installed the plugins I needed, including SubClipse. This time, though, I used SubClipse 1.10.x, and chose SVNKit. I created a fresh copy from backup of my workspace pre-upgrade. All projects now showed a correct repo path. For each project, I ran Team -> Upgrade. Then I ran a "compare with repository" to make sure I knew what was what. Then I ran Team -> Update to HEAD"; in a couple of cases, an identical file was copied into my workspace from the repo. If necessary, I then did a Team -> Commit. All is now well.

Comment: Summary: The primary problem was that the metadata needed upgrading, as Mark said. A secondary problem, however, was that JavaHL 1.7.x and SubClipse 1.8.x had problems with Kepler (or vice versa). It was not until I changed to SubClipse 1.10.x and SVNKit that I could use SVN reliably to correct the problems.